# Laravel Testing - Should I be creating dependant resources in each test?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, tdd

Starting on a new build with Laravel Spark 6 (Laravel 5.6) and decided to give TDD a try.

First test was lovely, I created a unit test to make sure that users can create an team.

(Pseudo code):

```
class AddNewTeamTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function admin_can_create_new_team()
    {
        // Create a user account

        $data = [
            // Information for tea,
        ];

        $response = $this->withHeaders([
                'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
            ])
            ->actingAs($user)
            ->json('POST', '/api/teams', $data);

        $response
            ->assertStatus(201);
    }

}
```

Using this in TDD style was a nice process, but now I want to be able to write a test for adding a member to that team.

It seems backwards that in this new test, I would run all of the code in my first test. Is there anyway around this? For the new test I would need a user and team already created before I could test adding a user to that team..

Any links or advice welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function `setUp()` and build your enviroment inside it. 
So your class should looks like that:

```
class AddNewTeamTest extends TestCase
    {

    protected  function setUp()
    {

        // Create a user account
        // Create your enviroment, etc.

        $this->actingAs($user)
    }


    /** @test */
    public function admin_can_create_new_team()
    {

        $data = [
            // Information for tea,
        ];

        $response = $this->withHeaders([
                'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
            ])
            ->json('POST', '/api/teams', $data);

        $response
            ->assertStatus(201);
    }

    public function testAnother()
    {
        \\your next test
    }
}
```

If you need a team in next few cases, that should be added in `setUp()`.

Also, you can make your next test needed ypur previous one. In that case you can return something in `admin_can_create_new_team()` and take as parameter in `testAnother()`

More info:
https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.test-dependencies